# Why my iPhone 6 screen resolution get differs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, screen-resolution, iphone-6

In my app, I have a condition to display a UIView in my view controllers if that view appears on the screen the iPhone 6 have the iPhone 5 resolution if that same view isn't appears there is no issue. I've calculated the screen resolution via code and test the above scenario. I think that Auto layout will change the screen resolution. Please help me to fix it. Also please share factors that changed the screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Select your View Controller, go to Attributes Inspector of the Utility Area and please ensure that you chose Inferred in Size 
 
[image] 
Enabling AutoLayout alone will not change your view's size.
You should add constraints to it. 
Once you are done, You need to set constraints for your view.
[image]